# How can i render microscope image using VTK library in python?

Tags: python, rendering, vtk

I have a couple of microscope image in a DICOM file and I want to render them using VTK. I was able to render CT DICOM images but I wasn't able to visualize microscopy one. The visualization box is showing after I run the below code but it doesn't show the image, I think it has something to do with colour or something else.
So my question is how can I fix it?

```
import vtk

# source—filter——mapper——actor——render——renderwindow——interactor
aRenderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(aRenderer)
# renWin.Render()
iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)


v16 = vtk.vtkDICOMImageReader()
v16.SetDirectoryName('/home/Micro/')


skinExtractor = vtk.vtkContourFilter()
skinExtractor.SetInputConnection(v16.GetOutputPort())
skinExtractor.SetValue(0, -10)
# skinExtractor.GenerateValues(2, 100, 110)
skinNormals = vtk.vtkPolyDataNormals()
skinNormals.SetInputConnection(skinExtractor.GetOutputPort())
skinNormals.SetFeatureAngle(60.0)
skinMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
skinMapper.SetInputConnection(skinNormals.GetOutputPort())
skinMapper.ScalarVisibilityOff()

skin = vtk.vtkActor()

skin.GetProperty().SetColor(0, 0, 1)
skin.SetMapper(skinMapper)

skin.GetProperty().SetDiffuseColor(0, 10, 1000)

skin.GetProperty().SetSpecular(100.5)

skin.GetProperty().SetSpecularPower(200)


outlineData = vtk.vtkOutlineFilter()
outlineData.SetInputConnection(v16.GetOutputPort())
mapOutline = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapOutline.SetInputConnection(outlineData.GetOutputPort())
outline = vtk.vtkActor()
outline.SetMapper(mapOutline)
outline.GetProperty().SetColor(0, 0, 0)


aCamera = vtk.vtkCamera()
aCamera.SetViewUp(0, 0, -1)
aCamera.SetPosition(0, 1, 0)
aCamera.SetFocalPoint(0, 0, 0)
aCamera.ComputeViewPlaneNormal()

aRenderer.AddActor(outline)
aRenderer.AddActor(skin)
aRenderer.SetActiveCamera(aCamera)

aRenderer.ResetCamera()
# aCamera.Dolly(1.5)
# aCamera.Roll(180)
# aCamera.Yaw(60)

aRenderer.SetBackground(250, 250, 250)
# renWin.SetSize(640, 480)

renWin.SetSize(500, 500)
aRenderer.ResetCameraClippingRange()

style = vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera()
iren.SetInteractorStyle(style)

iren.Initialize()
iren.Start()
```

Any suggestion?
And another question is, is there any better and efficient way to reconstruct the set of 120 Dicom images into 3D beside using VTK?
I don't think I will have much control over the colour option once it shows using VTK. true?

Comment: It depends a lot of the content in the image. In the above you have hard-coded a contour value of -10. If the microscopy image is strictly positive, you will get no contours. You should look deeper into what the individual functions do

Comment: @JensMunk First of all thanks for your comment. What do u mean by strictly positive? I tried changing every parameters but still, I can't visualize the image. I can visualize the same image in the 3D slice or in a paraview but not in python. I also couldn't find any example besides brain images for volume rendering.

Comment: You use a contour value of -10. If the image is strictly positive (all values > 0), you will see nothing. Are you sure that want to show contours?

Comment: I think the image is positive because it displays a range is from 0-255 (Here is the image file: https://uapt33090-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/ygupta_ua_pt/En9WthzU7PNLq1h7pnDO2TMBvmzj2jmCYxcSOueIeYvAZQ?e=hdsoVN). Even though after I change the contour value but still it didn't shows anything beside background.

Comment: If I change the contour value to +10, I see an image here. Try generate a range within the range of the value in the image

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It worked but the generated image is not in greyscale. Actually, I am pretty new to VTK implementation, I couldn't understand what are the main functions which play a vital role while forming an image. I can see that vtkColorTransferFunction, vtkPiecewiseFunction, and vtkContourFilter are some functions to which we can control the visibility of the image. But I couldn't understand how can I know the exact value of these functions or a range. And I also couldn't find a suitable example that can explain everything step by step so that I can follow it.

Comment: I will suggest that you start reading some of the many VTK tutorials :D